# Apache JMeter 5.5 - Need to use a specific range as Data value from a CSV file

Tags: loops, csv, jmeter, jmeter-5.0

I am currently using JMeter 5.5 and I have the below data set stored in a .csv file

| BatchId | DocID_Start | DocID_End |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 93 |
| 2 | 94 | 1266 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| 7 | 25313 | 45700 |

Each `BatchID` has 'n' number of Document ID ranging between `DocID_Start` and `DocID_End`.

I am trying to create a sampler that sends a `POST Drop loop` Call to the API `${url}/drop?documentIds=${DocID}`
where `DocID` is any number between the `DocID_Start` and `DocID_End`.

I Created a the following testplan
[image]

`GET Batch` is working as expected and it is looping through each of the `BatchID` within the CSV file one by one but I could not get `POST Drop Loop` to go through the CSV and grab a different `DocID_Start` value. It will just keep reusing the first line for every user.

I've tried using Loop Counter and ticked off different checkboxes but i couldn't get it to work

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With the default [Sharing Mode](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-csv-dataset-config) of `All threads` CSV Data Set Config reads the next line from the CSV file on each iteration of each virtual user.

If you want to get a random number between `DocID_Start` and `DocID_End` - go for [__Random() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__Random):

```
${__Random(${DocID_Start},${DocID_End},)}
```

you can call this function as many times as you want under the Loop Controller.

---

If I misunderstood your question and you want to proceed to the next "Batch" under the Loop Controller - you need to move your CSV Data Set Config **inside** the Loop Controller as currently it proceeds to the next line on the new iteration of the **Thread Group**. JMeter [Scoping Rules](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#scoping_rules) documentation chapter can shed some light on this.

Comment: Thank you for the tip @dmitri T. Right now my temporary solution is to do the random function you've mentioned. However what I am trying to do is to make sure that it loops the difference of `DocID_End - DocID_Start`. so from my example csv, `BatchID` 2, I'll need to make it loop 1266-94 = 1172 times while using the `DocID` 94, 95, 96 etc. 

1 User would be 1 line from the CSV and the sampler `POST Drop Loop` will run based on the range


I hope this helps clarify my question.